# TypeScript is using different versions of @types for react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have set my `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` with the following `paths`

```
"paths": {
  "react": ["node_modules/@types/react"],
  "@types/react":  ["node_modules/@types/react"]
}
```

Yet, I can see that `@types/react-router` is using it's own version of `@types/react` and this is causing compilation error, things like:

```
ERROR in /path/to/node_modules/@types/react-router/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts
    ERROR in /path/to/node_modules/@types/react-router/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2297,27)
       TS1005: ';' expected.
```

How do I force all modules to use the version of the @types I want to include?

Comment: You shouldn't get an extra copy of `@types/react` installed like that since the latest version of `@types/react-router` has a dependency on `@types/react` that allows any version.  What tool are you using to install packages?  (npm, yarn, something else?)  Please add your `package.json` file to the question so I can try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm install @types/yourModule --save-dev
```

can you try it

dont touch the tsconfig.json file